# formatting a bash output to json using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have the following output from a bash script and I want to convert it to the json format below using jq.  I am having difficulties in two thing:
1)- When I get to the sub levels
2)- I need to add an additional line containing mycustomvalue

The input will bring multiple lines but in the original format below, the values will be different for each line, which is expected and I will have a json files with multiple lines as well.  The mycustomvalue will be added to the bash output.

Here is what I tried so far.

```
jq -n '{g, first: {m: $one, v: $two, d: {a: $four, r: $five, s: $six, o: $seven, n: $eight}}}' \
>    --arg one 'myv1' \
>    --arg two 'myv6' \
>    --arg three 'myv3' \
>    --arg four 'myv2' \
>    --arg five 'myv5' \
>    --arg six 'mycustomvar'\
>    --arg seven 'myv4'\
>    --arg eight 'myv7'
{
  "g": null,
  "first": {
    "m": "myv1",
    "v": "myv6",
    "d": {
      "a": "myv2",
      "r": "myv5",
      "s": "mycustomvar",
      "o": "myv4",
      "n": "myv7"
    }
  }
}
```

Appreciate your opinion.

Original input

```
"value1: myv1",
"value2: myv2",
"value3: myv3",
"value4: myv4",
"value5: myv5",
"value6: myv6",
"value7: myv7"
```

Desired output:

```
{
    "g": [{
            "m": "myv1",
            "v": "myv6",
            "t":  myv3,
            "d": {
                "a": "myv2",
                "r": "myv5"
                "s": "mycustomvalue",
                "o": "myv4",
                "n": "myv7"
            }
        }, {
            "m": "myv1",
            "v": "myv6",
            "t":  myv3,
            "d": {
                "a": "myv2",
                "r": "myv5"             
                "s": "mycustomvalue",
                "o": "myv4",
                "n": "myv7"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why does the array have two identical elements?

Answer (score 1):

To get the expected output from your question, you have to change your jq filters slightly:

```
$ jq -n '{
  g: [
    range(2)
    | { 
      m: $one,
      v: $two,
      d: { a: $four, r: $five, s: $six, o: $seven, n: $eight }
      }
  ]
}' \
    --arg one 'myv1' \
    --arg two 'myv6' \
    --arg three 'myv3' \
    --arg four 'myv2' \
    --arg five 'myv5' \
    --arg six 'mycustomvar' \
    --arg seven 'myv4' \
    --arg eight 'myv7'
```

Output:

```
{
  "g": [
    {
      "m": "myv1",
      "v": "myv6",
      "d": {
        "a": "myv2",
        "r": "myv5",
        "s": "mycustomvar",
        "o": "myv4",
        "n": "myv7"
      }
    },
    {
      "m": "myv1",
      "v": "myv6",
      "d": {
        "a": "myv2",
        "r": "myv5",
        "s": "mycustomvar",
        "o": "myv4",
        "n": "myv7"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```